# nand bitwise operation in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, logic, bit-manipulation, mips, operation

I've been trying to figure out how to do a nand bitwise operation in assembly but have been unsuccessful.  I'm tried to write a logic gate simulator that will essentially produce this truth table for inputs A and B

```
   A  |   B  ||  F
  -----------------
   lo |  lo  ||  hi
   lo |  hi  ||  hi
   hi |  lo  ||  hi
   hi |  hi  ||  lo
```

I've tried everything.

```
  and  $t3,$t1,$t  
  not  $t4,$t3
```

Does not produce the correct output

Answer (score 1):

OF course it does, look at the truth table:

```
A    B    And   Nand
---------------------
lo   lo   lo    hi
lo   hi   lo    hi
hi   lo   lo    hi
hi   hi   hi    lo
```

As you can see, you can get nand values by negating previously anded values. But you may have forgotten that `and` and `not` operate on each bit of the registers. I think you confused with boolean values, where (usually) any non-zero value is assumed to be true. Therefore,

```
   11101001 nand 01000111 = 
 = ~ (11101001 and 01000111) =
 = ~ 01000001 = 
 = 10111110
```

because

```
1 and 0 = 0
1 and 1 = 1
1 and 0 = 0
0 and 0 = 0
1 and 0 = 0
0 and 1 = 0
0 and 1 = 0
1 and 1 = 1
```

Next time you should post both expected and actual results too, this way it is easier for us to understand what went wrong.

Comment: I'm new to MIPS so please forgive me.  So I guess I should only be concerned with the least signficant bit of the value in the register.   I don't know how to do that